# Can I remove/ uninstall "Toggle Desktop"?

Tags: 11.10, uninstall

[This is where I found out how to install it.](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/10/show-desktop-indicator-for-ubuntu-quick.html)

I tried `sudo apt-get remove wmctrl` but it did not work, even after reboot. I could not find anything on the Internet.

[image: It is the icon on the left, with the gears.]

It is the icon on the left, with the gears. Maybe there is a way to remove any of these icon (The Toggle Desktop)? Ones in the top bar? For the record I'm using Ubuntu 11.10

Answer (score 4):

This is the indicator author. To remove the icon from the panel you need only remove the app from "startup applications" as listed above. I personally use Ctrl+Alt+D to toggle the desktop. It is faster.

Answer (score 2):

The installation instructions state:

> To use it, firstly install `wmctrl`:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install wmctrl
> ```
>
> Then, download the archive from [here](http://markbokil.com/downloads/show-desktop.tar.gz), extract it and double click
>   the "desktop-indicator.py" file.
>
> To add Desktop Indicator to startup, search for "Startup Applications"
>   in Dash (or access it via the session menu - top right icon), click
>   "Add", under "Name" enter "Desktop Indicator" and under "Command"
>   click "Browse" and select "desktop-indicator.py" from where you've
>   extracted the downloaded archive.

Therefore to remove the indicator - at a minimum, would be to remove the application you have added via "Startup Applications" i.e.

search for "Startup Applications" in Dash (or access it via the session menu - top right icon), highlight "Desktop Indicator" and click the remove button.

Logout and login.